# Is there a such thing as a while each loop in Java?

Tags: java, while-loop

If there were such a thing I would imagine the syntax to be something along the lines of

```
while(Integer item : group<Integer>; item > 5)
{
    //do something
}
```

Just wondering if there was something like this or a way to imitate this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the closest would be:

```
for (Integer item : group<Integer>)
{
    if (item <= 5)
    {
        break;
    }
    //do something
}
```

Of course if Java ever gets concise closures, it would be reasonable to write something like .NET's [`Enumerable.TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx) method to wrap the iterable (`group` in this case) and make it finish early if the condition stops holding.

That's doable even now of course, but the code to do it would be ugly. For reference, the C# would look like this:

```
foreach (int item in group.TakeWhile(x => x > 5))
{
    // do something
}
```

Maybe Java will get nice closures some time...

Comment: Hehe. Beat me by a few seconds again. btw...I think you intended the to use 'for' instead of 'while' in the first line of your code snippet.

Comment: Hm. I don't recognize that while syntax.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(Integer item : group<Integer>)
{
    if (item <= 5)
         break;
    //do something
}
```

This is what I can think of.

Comment: Exactly my suggestion, except that your condition looks like it's the wrong way round to me.

Comment: It's fine now - it was originally "if (item > 5)"

Comment: So he asked and answered his own question all in 4 minutes? :P

Comment: I can figure out a way to do most things, what I'm left wondering is whether it is the best way, if there were a such thing as a while each loop that would have been better. I figured I would let the votes decide if I had a decent approach to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, Jon Skeet's second answer in Java would currently, for some `interface Predicate`, look something like:

```
for (int item : takeWhile(group, new Predicate<Integer>() {
    public boolean contains(Integer x) {
        return x > 5;
    }
}) {
    // do something
}
```

It's the syntax that sucks, not the semantics.

Comment: thanks I was wondering about that, that syntax definitely sucks

Answer (score 0):

In Java `while` is condition based. What you are looking for is the `foreach` construct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like while-each in Java but we've got for -each which is so great.